# Foreach is not processing each item, tries to process all as one line

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am building a script to pull the mac addresses of a computer, and convert them to GUIDs that are then queried to AD to find a match and retrieve the hostname associate with that guid.

Everything I've read about "Foreach" suggests that the code I am using "SHOULD" work.

```
$NIC = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select MacAddress
$NICMacs = $NIC.MacAddress

Foreach ($NICMac in $NICMacs)
{

$MacString = $NICMacs -replace ":", ""
$MactoGUID = "00000000000000000000" + $MacString
$MactoGUID = $MactoGUID -replace " ", ''
$NBG = [GUID]$MactoGUID
$CompDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'netbootGUID -like $NBG' -Properties netBootGUID -Server our.AD.server.ca -Credential $sessionKey
```

This should process each mac address found, stripping away the: characters and prepending 20 '0s' then convert to GUID format and query AD for a match.
Instead, it takes all the mac addresses found, concatenates them to one line and tries to process with all those numbers. Of course AD rejects it as an incorrect GUID.
If I use the same code with only 1 mac address, it is correctly formatted.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using

Comment: Looks like a simple typo, inside the loop you should be using the `$NICMac` variable but you've used the original `$NICMacs` variable instead

Comment: as others have mentioned, you used the wrong $Var in the loop. this `$MacString = $NICMacs -replace ":", ""` uses the _collection_ $Var instead of the current item $Var. [*grin*] ///// this is one reason you should ALWAYS try to use **_vividly different names for the collection and the current item_**. in your case, a better pair of names would be `Foreach ($NL_Item in $NICMacList)`.

Comment: Sorry, new to posting here, it was powershell :)
I did try referencing $NICMac in the foreach, but all it returned was the 20 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your steps can be combined and thus save intermediate vars using

- `Select-Object -ExpandProperty MacAddress`
- `.PadLeft()` method

As [@RobV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107591/robv) already pointed out in his comment usage of the wrong var caused the malfunction.

```
Foreach ($NICMac in (Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
                       Where-Object MacAddress -ne '' |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty MacAddress) ) {
    $NBG = [GUID]($NICMac -replace ':').PadLeft(32,'0')
    $CompDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'netbootGUID -like $NBG' `
      -Properties netBootGUID -Server our.AD.server.ca -Credential $sessionKey
}
```

I don't consider usage of a line continuation character esoteric,
here it allows keeping the overview.

I agree that [Natural Line Continuations in PowerShell](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html) are preferable.

Comment: Instead of using esoteric line continuations for a long parameterset, I'd suggest utilizing splatting with a small footnote if you think the asker wouldn't understand it.  Additionally, you don't explain *why* what the OP is doing isn't *working*.

Comment: Thanks @RobV! I'll test it out at work on Monday, but on my home comp (not in AD) the foreach worked as I had hoped and gave a positive result in $NBG

Answer (score 0):

A couple items here:

1. In your code, in line 7, you reference $NICMacs, but you should be referencing $NICMac since the foreach is running through the logic separately, not as a batch.
2. You could simplify at least the top two lines into a single line without a pipe.

```
$NICMacs = (Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).MacAddress

Foreach ($NICMac in $NICMacs)
{

$MacString = $NICMac -replace ":", ""
$MactoGUID = "00000000000000000000" + $MacString
[GUID]$NBG = $MactoGUID -replace " ", ''
$CompDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'netbootGUID -like $NBG' -Properties netBootGUID -Server our.AD.server.ca -Credential $sessionKey
```

Edit: in my suggested code, I think making $NBG should work with the [GUID] tag in front but I've never tried it

Comment: I just get the added 0's with this implementation, which is what I was getting previously when I tried everyones suggestion of referencing $NICMac in the foreach statement